# Does Mathematica 11 work on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: mac-os-x, system

I'm not sure if I should upgrade, so I wanted to see if anyone has used v11 sucessfully on the newest OSX?

---

This is the discussion about the same topic [on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/928500).

Comment: Be careful about opening the font adjuster (format -> Fonts), that seemed to reliably crash M for me earlier today.

Comment: The [Revision History](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.en.html?footer=lang) states that version 11.0.1 improves the compatibility with macOS Sierra.

Comment: So far I've only run into the two problems mentioned in the answers below: (1) when moving a 3D graphic - complete system crash requiring reboot (apparently fixed with v11.0.1 according to this [Wolfram Community discussion](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/930646)), and (2) an error when pulling up the fonts panel with Show Fonts. Other than that, Mathematica appears to be working just fine.

Comment: The answer you accepted is inaccurate and it doesn't even state what version s/he was using. There are in fact multiple problems with 11.0.0 on Sierra, some of which are fixed in 11.0.1.

Comment: v11.0.1 works fine for me. v11.0.0 had more problems than I've experienced with Mma for a long while when ran under Sierra - many features relying on dynamic functionality resulted gray boxes and odd renderings, even to the point of Find dialog showing up as a gray window on the first try. (These things occurred both in betas and the released version.) All of these issues went away with v11.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer to summarize the other answers and give an overview of the situation.

---

Mathematica 11.0 does have problems on Sierra.

- **Version 11.0.0:**

  - Some people report crashes while displaying or rotating 3D graphics (`Graphics3D`)
  - The Format -> Show Fonts menu item triggers a crash not only in v11.0.0 but also in previous versions
- **Version 11.0.1:**

  - The `Graphics3D` crash is fixed
  - Format -> Show Fonts is disabled on Sierra (but not on earlier OS X). `Style` (or editing cell expressions directly) can still be used to set fonts programmatically.

---

The Mathematica version can be checked using `{$VersionNumber, $ReleaseNumber}`.

The discussion of these issues on Wolfram Community is found [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/928500).

[Mathematica Release History](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html)

---

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it works well. No issues, other than crashes when opening fonts, yet.

[image]

Comment: I have a similar system ( see my answer below) running any simple code with graphics3d freezes my laptop completely. @user5601 can you give it a try?

Comment: Do you find that the scrolling is as smooth as before? what I mean is that if I scroll very slowly nothing happens. I have to swipe fast in order for the scroll bar to move.

Comment: Answering my question... it seems they fix it in 11.0.1 http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT 2016-10-06:
I just tried version 11.0.1.0 and Graphichs3D is working!

Not working at all with Graphics3D. Evaluating the following line and trying to rotate the graph with the mouse completely freezes my mac.

```
Graphics3D[Line@{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}}]
```

The only way to fix after that is to hard reboot my laptop. 
@user5601 Can you try the above code and reports on the results? I think your system is similar to mine.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem as described above on my Late 2013 retina 13 inch MacBook Pro

Comment: Did you contact Wolfram Support?  What did they say?

Comment: [There's a discussion of similar problems on Wolfram Community.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/930646)

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Crashes my computer when I try to rotate a 3D graph on my 2015 Mac mini.  I have to reboot to get out of it.  I also get strange lines across the entire screen.  Very frustrating.  How do I get the beta version of Mathematica 11.0.1.0 mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Mathematica 11 works fine on macOS Sierra 10.12. Currently, I am running it on the following platform:

Mac Mini (Mid 2011)
2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
8 GB RAM
macOS Sierra 10.12

All the best,
Richard

Answer (score 4):

It seems break your computer for any 3D stuff as of now. I talked to a Mathematica software engineer this past weekend, he submitted the bug himself.

Answer (score 3):

I just installed v11.0.1 and the problem with Show Fonts is still there. 
It is even worse in the sense that the "Show Fonts" line is inactive (shaded).
So no crash, but also no functionality at all...

Comment: Does the "Show Fonts" problem persist after the mac OS Sierra 10.12.1 update?

Answer (score 2):

No problem on my iMac, yet. I must say I have been working a lot with it until now. I will cross my fingers...

[image: My iMacs specs]

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS 10.12.1 iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010) my new Mathematica 11.01.0

"Show Fonts" menu item is grey. All styles show the same font.