# Use two kinds of the font in FrameLabel

Tags: fonts, frame

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
FrameLabel -> {"x (rad)", "Signal (%)"}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 25, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}]
```

[image]
How can I use two kinds of the font in FrameLabel at the same time?

Like, I want to let "(%)" in "Latin Modern Math" but others are in Times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** In principle the simplest answer is the same as [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28108/245): use the `Show Fonts` menu. However, that menu item is [grayed out in *Mathematica* version 11.0.1 on macOS Sierra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130287/245). The following is a workaround for that bug.
**End Edit**

To make the desired adjustments interactively, select the `%` in your source code, then go to the menu `Format > Option Inspector`. It will open a pane that shows all the things you can modify for the current selection. Among them is `Formatting Options > Font Options > FontFamily` which you can now adjust using the drop-down menu.

[image: screen shot]

Once you press shift-enter, the label as you formatted it will be preserved because it's already wrapped in a `StyleBox` automatically, without you having to enter the code for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a very clear description :)

Answer (score 1):

```
FrameLabel -> {"x (rad)", 
  Row[
   {Text[Style["Signal", 24, FontFamily -> "Times"]], 
    Text[Style[" (%)", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly in some of my trivial and similar graphs!